# Call to undefined function mysqli_result::num_rows()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a result, and I keep getting the above returned error.  I've checked the manual, and I'm using mysqli_result::num_rows() as I should be (I'm using object oriented style.)  I've got three classes working here.

Class (Connection):

```
class utils_MysqlImprovedConnection {
    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db)
    {
        $this->_connection = @new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot access database:' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function getResultSet($sql)
    {
        $results = new utils_MysqlImprovedResult($sql, $this->_connection);
        return $results;
    }

    public function  __destruct() {
        $this->_connection;
    }
}
```

Class (Handles Result):

```
class utils_MysqlImprovedResult implements Iterator, Countable {
    protected $_key;
    protected $_current;
    protected $_valid;
    protected $_result;


    public function  __construct($sql, $connection) {
       if (!$this->_result = $connection->query($sql)){
           throw new RuntimeException($connection->error . '. The actual query submitted was: '. $sql);
       }
    }

    public function  rewind()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_key)){
            $this->_result->data_seek(0);
        }
        $this->_current = $this->_result->fetch_assoc();
        $this->_valid = is_null($this->_current) ? false : true;
    }
    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->_valid;
    }
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->_current;
    }
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->_key;
    }
    public function next()
    {
        $this->_current = $this->_result->fetch_assoc();
        $this->_valid = is_null($this->_current) ? false : true;
        $this->_key++;
    }
    public function count()
    {
        $this->_result->store_result();
        $this->_result->num_rows();
    }
}
```

Class function:

```
public function resetPassword($email, $pass){
    //check if email exists, update authkey and password, send email
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$email'";
    $results = $this->_db->getResultSet($sql);
    if($results->count() == 1){
        // Process
        $this->_message = "Success!";
        return $this->_message;
    } else {
        // Not unique
        $this->_error = "Try again";
       return $this->_error;
    } 
}
```

The test page I'm using to call all this is (include statement is just __autoload() function that is working fine):

```
$columnvar = 'emailaddress@test.com';
$pass = 'blah';
require_once 'inc.init.php';
$user = new utils_User();
try{
   $string = $user->resetPassword($email, $pass);
   echo $string;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Note: I originally didn't have the:

Comment: Note: I originally didn't have the 'code' $this->store_result(); 'code' in the funciton, just added it after some research and thought it might help.

Comment: Remove the brackets. $this->_result->num_rows();  to  $this->_result->num_rows; It worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the manual, it seems that [mysqli_result::num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) isn't a function, but rather a variable containing the number of rows.

It can be used like this:

```
$num_rows = $mysqli_result->num_rows;
```

The function equivalent is `mysqli_num_rows($result)`, where you pass in the `mysqli_result` object, but that's if you're using the procedural style rather than object oriented style.

In your code, you should change your `count()` function in the `utils_MysqlImprovedResult` class to be like this (I'm assuming that's the function where you're getting the error message),

```
public function count()
{
    // Any other processing you want
    // ...
    return $this->_result->num_rows;
}
```

or alternatively if you want to mix OO and procedural styles (probably a bad idea),

```
public function count()
{
    // Any other processing you want
    // ...
    return mysqli_num_rows($this->_result);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that how it's being used here?  I checked the manual, and this is exactly how it's used in the manual also.

Comment: In your code you have "$this->_result->num_rows();", this isn't how it's used in the manual. In the manual it's described as "int $mysqli_result->num_rows;" (note the lack of function braces "()"). Change it to "return $this->_result->num_rows;" in your code and it should work.

Comment: Thank you...  Was my first ever question on here.  Pleasure doin business with ya.